# Adding event to device calendar not working in marshmallow android

Tags: android, events, calendar

Hi I have added event to device calendar using below code,

```
 ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, DateConversion.getMilliSecondFromString(eventStartDate));
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, DateConversion.getMilliSecondFromString(eventEndDate));
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, title);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, comment);
        TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, timeZone.getID());
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1);
  if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
   return;
}
        Uri uri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
        if (uri!=null){
            Log.d(TAG, "event addEventToMyCalendar: Uri=>"+Long.valueOf(uri.getLastPathSegment()));
            Toast.makeText(this,"Event Added To Calendar",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else {
            Log.d(TAG, "event addEventToMyCalendar: Uri=>Null");
        }
```

and my log value is,

**event addToEventToMyCalendar: title=>Louvre Museum=>eventStartDate=>2016-09-26 10:00:00=>comment=>In the former royal palace of French Kings, the Louvre is an incomparable museum that ranks among the top European collections of fine arts. Many of...=>eventEndDate=>2016-09-26 12:00:00**

**event addEventToMyCalendar: Uri=>100**

but this event is not displayed in my device calendar.

This code is working below marshmallow. But this is not working in marshmallow.

I have also added runtime permission for WRITE_CALENDAR.

Could you please suggest me any idea to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void addToDeviceCalendar(String startDate,String endDate, String title,String description, String location) {

        String stDate = startDate;
        String enDate = endDate;

        GregorianCalendar calDate = new GregorianCalendar();
        //GregorianCalendar calEndDate = new GregorianCalendar();

        SimpleDateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
        SimpleDateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy,MM,dd,HH,mm");
        Date date,edate;
        try {
            date = originalFormat.parse(startDate);
            stDate=targetFormat.format(date);

        } catch (ParseException ex) {}

        long startMillis = 0;
        long endMillis = 0;
        String dates[] = stDate.split(",");

        SD_YeaR = dates[0];
        SD_MontH = dates[1];
        SD_DaY = dates[2];
        SD_HouR = dates[3];
        SD_MinutE = dates[4];


        /*Log.e("YeaR ", SD_YeaR);
        Log.e("MontH ",SD_MontH );
        Log.e("DaY ", SD_DaY);
        Log.e(" HouR", SD_HouR);
        Log.e("MinutE ", SD_MinutE);*/

        calDate.set(Integer.parseInt(SD_YeaR), Integer.parseInt(SD_MontH)-1, Integer.parseInt(SD_DaY), Integer.parseInt(SD_HouR), Integer.parseInt(SD_MinutE));
        startMillis = calDate.getTimeInMillis();
/*
        try {
            edate = originalFormat.parse(endDate);
            enDate=targetFormat.format(edate);

        } catch (ParseException ex) {}


        String end_dates[] = endDate.split(",");

        String ED_YeaR = end_dates[0];
        String ED_MontH = end_dates[1];
        String ED_DaY = end_dates[2];

        String ED_HouR = end_dates[3];
        String ED_MinutE = end_dates[4];


        calEndDate.set(Integer.parseInt(ED_YeaR), Integer.parseInt(ED_MontH)-1, Integer.parseInt(ED_DaY), Integer.parseInt(ED_HouR), Integer.parseInt(ED_MinutE));
        endMillis = calEndDate.getTimeInMillis();*/

        try {
            ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getContentResolver();
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, calDate.getTimeInMillis() + 60 * 60 * 1000);
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, title);
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, description);
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION,location);
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.HAS_ALARM,1);
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1);
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, Calendar.getInstance()
                    .getTimeZone().getID());
            System.out.println(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone().getID());
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                return;
            }
            Uri uri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);

            long eventId = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());
            Log.d("Ketan_Event_Id", String.valueOf(eventId));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Other than just writing the code and leave it, the answer could be more improved by adding description of the steps, that you took in achievig the goal. This will help readers understand your code better. Without that your answer is long block of confusing codes.

Comment: Tried this , but still issue exist. Am getting EventId but event is not displayed in my device calendar.